# Prove the sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to see that the real sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ given by

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{1}=1\\ 
x_{n+1}=(-1)^n \sqrt{4+5|x_{n}|}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}

is bounded. At first glance I cannot establish a dimension for such a sequence, since some terms are $\{1, -3, \sqrt{19}, \dots \}$

Now, I was thinking of proving that this sequence converges and is therefore bounded. To do so, I could consider the subsequences $\{x_{2k}\}$ and $\{x_{2k-1}\}$ with $k$ integer; If both subsequences converge to the value $L$ then $\{x_{n}\}$ will do the same but I am not sure if this is the most optimal way. Any help with proving that this sequence is bounded is welcome.

Comment: I don't think the sequence is bounded.

Comment: I think you can show (with induction) that $|x_n| \le 6$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson for $x_1=1$ it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x_n| \le 6$ then
$$
 |x_{n+1}| = \sqrt{4+5|x_n|} \le \sqrt{34} < 6 \, ,
$$
which shows that $|x_n| \le 6$ for all $n$.

Slightly better, one can show that $|x_n|$ is bounded by $a =(\sqrt{41}+5)/2 \approx 5.702$, which is the solution of the equation $a = \sqrt{4+5a}$.

(Actually the sequence $(|x_n|)$ is increasing and converges to $a$, so that $x_{2n} \to -a$ and $x_{2n-1} \to a$.)

Comment: This still works? even knowing that $x_{9}=\sqrt{49}=7$?, i see thath the terms are $\{1, -3, \sqrt{19}, -\sqrt{24}, \sqrt{29}, -\sqrt{34}, \sqrt{39}, -\sqrt{44}, \sqrt{49}=7 \}$

Comment: @Wrloord: According to my calculation is  $x_4 \approx -5.0788 \ne -\sqrt{24}$ and $x_9 \approx 5.691018$.

Comment: @Wrloord Yes, your fourth value onwards is wrong.

Comment: That's right, I saw the error, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$a_n=|x_n|, \Rightarrow a_{n+1}=\sqrt{4+5a_{n}}$$

By induction, it is easy to show $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$.

Let $A=\frac{5+\sqrt{41}}2$ which satisfies $A^2-5A-4=0$

By induction, assume it is true for $a_n<A$

$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{4+5a_n}<\sqrt{4+5A}=\sqrt{A^2}=A\Rightarrow a_{n+1}<A$$

So $a_n$ is monotonic increasing, and bounded by $A$. Actually it is easy to verify $a_n$ converges to $A$.

For you case, $\lim x_{2n+1}\rightarrow A$, and $\lim x_{2n}\rightarrow -A$

Comment: I honestly don't understand why $\lim x_{2n} \rightarrow -A$ perhaps because it is not entirely clear to me how it is defined the sequence $x_{2n}$, Could you help me to clarify the reason for this limit?